# Integration of custom methods in browsable api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an application that has `Item` and `Customer` objects. The `Customer` has a property `watchList` which is a list of `Item`.

Now I want to create a REST api for these watch lists. It should list all items in the watch list of the current customer and offer a method to add (already existing) items to the list.

```
class WatchListViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Customer.objects.get(user = self.request.user).watchList

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Customer.objects.get(user = self.request.user).watchList
        serializer = ItemSerializer(queryset, context={'request': request}, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @list_route(methods=['POST'])
    def add(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #request.data.id contains the id of the item that should be added
        # ...
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

However, when I request `localhost:800/api/watchList/add/`, I see a form for an `item` not an input for the id of an existing item (or even better, a dropdown/selection field).

How can I inform the browsable api that the requested input type differs from the rest of the view set? Can this be connected to some kind of automatic validation (the method won't be executed if no id is passed)?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this solves my problem:

```
class ItemIdSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id',)
```

and

```
class WatchListViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_serializer(self):
        if self.action == WatchListViewSet.add.__name__:
            return ItemIdSerializer()
        return super(WatchListViewSet, self).get_serializer()
```

The method `get_serializer` returns the special `ItemIdSerializer` if the `add` action is executed.
By defining the attribute `id` as `serializers.IntegerField()` the default behaviour of hiding the read-only attribute `id` is overwritten.

However, this approach doesn't provide any automatic verification, it's still possible to execute the `add` method without providing an id.